# Statically served NextJS website is adding a trailing slash on page refresh

Tags: .htaccess, next.js

I have a NextJS website statically served on an apache server and using an `.htaccess` file to setup the routing rules etc. This files looks like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
    RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

### The problem I'm facing:

My internal links look like `example.com/page-1`, so when I redirect from `example.com` to `example.com/page-1` everything is working well.

But when I target this page directly from it's URL or reload the page the server is adding a extra trailing slash to the URL. e.g. `example.com/page-1/`

This causes duplicate content within search engines /

### What I'm looking for:

I'm looking for a solution in my `.htaccess` that prevents the server from adding a trailing slash on reloading the page. But URL's like `example.com/about/page-1` should keep working.

Comment: Do you have trailing slash enabled? https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/trailing-slash

Comment: No, I explicitly turned this off (`trailingSlash: false,`)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for my own problem. The problem was causes because I copied this `.htaccess` from an old React project where it was supporting the react-router.

Within my NextJS project I only had to remove the `.html` extension inside the `.htaccess` file. See example below:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: "I only had to remove the .html extension" - note that this does not "remove" the `.html` extension, it _adds_ it (the opposite). (The `.html` extension has - presumably - already been removed in your links.) _Aside:_ This appends the `.html` on any URL that does not map to a file, so `/anything` is rewritten to `/anything.html` - regardless of whether that file exists or not. Ideally, you would check that the `.html` file exists first _before_ rewriting the request. The `<IfModule>` wrapper serves no purpose here. And no need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive.